# Help with some algebra on a lognormal variable raised to a power.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, statistics

While this is technically a statistics question, I think my shortcoming is due to forgetting a more basic math principle.

$1 + \widetilde{\epsilon}$ is log-normally distributed where $1+\widetilde{\epsilon} = e^\widetilde{z}$ and $z$ has var $\sigma^2$ and mean $\frac{-\sigma^2}{2}$. I want to show that from $\frac{1}{1-\rho}\left[(1-b)x\right]^{1-\rho} = \mathbb{E}\left[\frac{1}{1-\rho}(x(1+\widetilde{\epsilon}))^{1-\rho} \right]$ we can get to $b = 1-e^{-\rho\sigma^2/2}$.

Here's my work so far.
$$\frac{1}{1-\rho}\left[(1-b)x\right]^{1-\rho} = \mathbb{E}\left[\frac{1}{1-\rho}(x(1+\widetilde{\epsilon}))^{1-\rho} \right]$$

Goes to

$$(1-b)^{1-\rho} = \mathbb{E}\left[(1+\widetilde{\epsilon})^{1-\rho}\right]$$

I want to take the natural log of both sides but the expectation makes it so I'm stuck right afterwards. I also thought about using the property that $\mathbb{E}[\widetilde{x}]=e^{\mu-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2}$ but the $1-\rho$ gets in the way of that...

Ideas?

---

If I take $\lim_p \rightarrow \inf$ then I can get what to $b = 1-e^{-\sigma^2/2}$ no problem but my text wants the $\rho$ to be there.

Comment: Does the tilde denote something? Why does it appear on certain symbols but not others?

Comment: @angryavian it just means that it's a random variable. I'll add it within all the expectation signs. Sorry for the bad notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $z$ is normal with mean $\mu$ and variance $\nu^2$, then [$E[e^{tz}] = e^{\mu t + \nu^2 t^2 / 2}$ (moment generating function)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Moment_and_cumulant_generating_functions). Then plug in $\mu = -\sigma^2/2$ and $\nu^2 = \sigma^2$ to get

\begin{align}
E[(1+\epsilon)^{1-\rho}]
= E[e^{(1-\rho)z}]
= e^{-\frac{\sigma^2}{2}(1-\rho) + \frac{\sigma^2 (1-\rho)^2}{2}}
= e^{-\frac{\sigma^2}{2}\rho(1-\rho)}
\end{align}
which gives you what you want.

Comment: you're a wizard. Thank you.

Comment: how come the second part is $E[e^{(1-p)z}]$ and not $E[e^{z^{1-p}}]$?

Comment: Check that $(a^b)^c = a^{bc}$. (Note that $a^{b^c}=a^{(b^c)}$ is something different, but not relevant here.)

Comment: I'm probably being a bit dense, but how did you move from the $E[(1+\epsilon)^{1-\rho}]$ to $E[e^{(1-\rho)z}]$. To me, it looks like replacing $1+ \epsilon$ with its definition as $e^z$ and since the former was raised to $1-\rho$ it seems like the latter would be too?

Comment: I see now, we're good. Sorry! Time to go to bed haha